# How to blob only the image on a canvas without the remnant?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, blob

My canvas is the whole grey box and inside an image is drawn. It looks like that:

[image: canvas]

And with

```
generateBlob (callback, mimeType, qualityArgument) {
  if (!this.hasImage()) {
    callback(null)
    return
  }
  this.canvas.toBlob(callback, mimeType, qualityArgument)
},
```

I can get the blob via promise. But the problem is that I get the image with the **gray bar**. Is it possible?

**Additional Information:**

I use a component that is called [vue-croppa](https://github.com/zhanziyang/vue-croppa/blob/master/src/cropper.vue).

Because the code is very long I try to show you the important parts how the image is drawn:

```
_drawFrame () {
   //...
   //ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d')
   ctx.drawImage(this.img, startX, startY, width, height)
   //
}
```

Comment: Is that grey bar in the image?

Comment: @evolutionxbox The whole square you see is the canvas element. And the image is drawn.

Comment: Can you show some more code? You haven't shown how you put the image into the canvas. --- It also looks like a aspect ratio issue.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I added some additional information. I try to shorten it, the code is not very friendly to read. If you need more informations I will answer right away (trying to :)

Comment: What if you change the width/height of `drawImage` to match the canvas size exactly.

Comment: The toBlob method does not provide any means to cut only part of the canvas content; you will have to create a canvas with dimensions matching the image dimensions first.

Comment: @evolutionxbox well I don't want to match the canvas size. It should behave like the "canvas" used by the instagram app. So I can have different aspect ratio when getting the Image.

Comment: Are you changing the canvas size?

Comment: @CBroe well.. I feard of that

Comment: @evolutionxbox No. The canvas size is fixed with 300px width and 300px height.

Comment: In my mind if the image doesn’t match the canvas aspect ratio you’re going to get empty space (grey space in this case).

Answer (score 0):

My solution feels a bit ugly but works. I created another canvas and load the image inside and create the blob after that. But it requires you to have the HTMLImageelement and the width and height of it.

```
createCanvas(){
    this.imgCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    this.imgCtx = this.imgCanvas.getContext("2d");

    this.imgCanvas.width = this.croppa.imgData.width;
    this.imgCanvas.height = this.croppa.imgData.height;

    this.imgCtx.drawImage(this.croppa.img, 0, 0, this.croppa.imgData.width, this.croppa.imgData.height); 
},
```

Comment: You can drawImage a canvas so you don't need the HTMLImageElement.